# Are HTML based password reset templates reliably rendered?

Tags: email-template, email, passwords, html

I notice that salesforce seems to simply append the username and password at the end of the template, as far as anyone is aware are the resulting documents always well formed and reliably rendered across all email clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we have tested **Text** and **HTML with Letterhead** extensively and they all render fine in various email clients. If you were to create a raw html template or a visualforce template, I believe that the username/password is placed outside of your markup which can cause some unintended layout issues. Stick to **Text** or **HTML with Letterhead** and you should be fine.